Argocd ApplicationSet Webhook Sync + Appplication Wenhook Sync using same payload URL
https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd/blob/master/util/webhook/webhook.go
=======================================================================
https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd/blob/master/applicationset/webhook/webhook.go
I would like to seek advise, is that achievable if Argocd environment configured for ApplicationSet Webhook Sync and Application App Webhook sync using the same payload URL ?
would like to know same payload URL working for 2 different services.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
